# How to remove comma after a word pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

Please help me out to get the specific `regex` to remove comma after a word pattern in java.
Assume, I would like to delete comma after each pattern where the  pattern is `<Word$TAG>, <Word$TAG>, <Word$TAG>, <Word$TAG>, <Word$TAG>`  now I want my output to be `<Word$TAG> <Word$TAG>  <Word$TAG>  <Word$TAG>` . if I used `.replaceAll()`, it will replace all commas, but in my `<Word$TAG>` Word may have a comma(,).

For example, **Input.txt** is as follows

```
mms§NNP_ACRON, site§N_NN, pe§PSP, ,,,,,§RD_PUNC, link§N_NN, ....§RD_PUNC, CID§NNP_ACRON, team§N_NN, :)§E
```

and **Output.txt**

```
mms§NNP_ACRON site§N_NN pe§PSP ,,,,,§RD_PUNC link§N_NN ....§RD_PUNC CID§NNP_ACRON team§N_NN :)§E
```

Comment: Do you want to change all `<specific tag>,` to `<specific tag>`? I didnt get what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ", " as search and replace it with " " (space) as below:

```
one.replace(", ", " ");
```

If you think, you have "myString, ,,," or multiple spaces in between, then you could use replace all with regex like

```
one.replaceAll(",\\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[^,\s]),
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/5

Answer (score 0):

**Match the data you *want*, not the one you *don't* want.**

You probably want `([^ ]+),` and keep the bracketed data, separated by whitespace.

You might even want to narrow it down to `([^ ]+§[^ ]+),`. Usually, stricter is better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookahead assertion to match all the commas which are followed by a space or end of the line anchor.

```
String s = "mms§NNP_ACRON, site§N_NN, pe§PSP, ,,,,,§RD_PUNC, link§N_NN, ....§RD_PUNC, CID§NNP_ACRON, team§N_NN, :)§E";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll(",(?=\\s|$)",""));
```

**Output:**

```
mms§NNP_ACRON site§N_NN pe§PSP ,,,,,§RD_PUNC link§N_NN ....§RD_PUNC CID§NNP_ACRON team§N_NN :)§E
```